# React bootstrap auto layout columns not being responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to follow the Auto Layout [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#auto-layout) of React Bootstrap and when it's displaying on my code, it's giving the column values its own space and not allowing them to be responsive like in the documentation.

Here's the code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Container fluid>
      <Row className="row">
        <Col className="column">1 of 2</Col>
        <Col className="column">2 of 2</Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="row">
        <Col className="column">1 of 3</Col>
        <Col className="column">2 of 3</Col>
        <Col className="column">3 of 3</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you check the "auto layout" section of the docs, it should have the same effect where columns take up the space of the first one for as long as they can.

I've already

- added react-bootstrap and installed via the terminal

[image]

As you can see, '2 of 2' should be on the same level as '1 of 2' and it should be halfed based on the auto layout property in the documentation, but it's not doing it.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Comment: @Sowam Nope sorry it didn't work. :(

Comment: Can you create a sandbox? @JRP

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't put div around it, you can add empty element <> there like

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      //rest of code
    </>
  );
}
```

or better option - use react [fragment](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
 function App() {
      return (
     <Fragment>
        // rest of code
      </Fragment>
      );
    }
```

second thing - you don't have to add any classNames to bootstrap elements. Rows and Cols would be styled automatically so your code should look like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
   <Fragment>
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>1 of 2</Col>
        <Col>2 of 2</Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col>1 of 3</Col>
        <Col>2 of 3</Col>
        <Col>3 of 3</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
   </Fragment>
  );
}
```

it should work, if doesn't, you definitely import bootstrap in wrong way

Comment: Good, this is a lot a good practices, but it will not resolve his problem.

Comment: @ViniciusKatata in your answer you say that guy that uses react should import bootstrap in link rel... which is totally wrong. In react you import libraries by import in the beginning, not in link rels

Comment: @Sowam Avoiding additional div is good. To make the answer complete, I think you should also add a note for OP about importing the stylesheet as suggested in [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css). Good point about removing "className".

Comment: And one can use either *import* or *link* but using `import` is [just better for reasons listed in the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system). : *Scripts and stylesheets get minified and bundled together to avoid extra network requests*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same column alignment issue with react-bootstrap.  I started with `npm i react-bootstrap` and `npm i bootstrap`.  Partial code for the columns:

```
import '../App.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

function TimeGrid() {
    return (
        <div id="time-grid-container">
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>Day</Col>
                    <Col>Clock In</Col>
                    <Col>Clock Out</Col>
                    <Col>Clock In</Col>
                    <Col>Clock Out</Col>
                    <Col>Day Total</Col>
                    <Col>Week Total</Col>
                </Row>
```

Reading over [React-Bootstrap Getting Started - Stylesheets](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets) mentions "Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components."

Adding the following import to my src/index.js fixed the column alignment issue:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Full index.js code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you not importing the css of `react-bootstrap`

Just add

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

into your `index.html`
or

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

in your `App.js`, `Root.js`
Both should work,
found [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css)

Comment: He is using react probably so you can't import bootstrap like that. You use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction this documentation for that

Comment: Of course, he can. It is his project, not ours. Both will work, just like the doc says `How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you...`